# PHP header redirect using script-Syntax error

Tags: php

I am trying to do a header redirect using script.I am not well versed with PHP/JS but i can make out there is some syntax error which i am not able to troubleshoot. Following is the code. Experts, please help.

```
<?php $sendvar = "?subject=".$subjectfromemail."&from=".=$from."&message=".$messagefromemail."&wrong_code=true";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
window.top.location='$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']+$sendvar';
</script>"; exit;?>
```

Comment: There is a lot of help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be able to use an array value inside of a string, please enclose it with curly brackets like this:

```
<?php $sendvar = "?subject=".$subjectfromemail."&from=".=$from."&message=".$messagefromemail."&wrong_code=true";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
window.top.location='{$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}+$sendvar';
</script>"; exit;?>
```

Regards,

Stefan

Comment: This worked. I had to do couple of modification to finally get it functional. <?php $sendvar = "?subject=".$subjectfromemail."&from=".$from."&message=".$messagefromemail."&wrong_code=true";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
window.top.location='{$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}$sendvar';
</script>"; exit;?> Thanks Stefan!

Answer (score 1):

You can do redirect using PHP itself.

[How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

```
$sendvar = "?subject=".$subjectfromemail."&from=".=$from."&message=".$messagefromemail."&wrong_code=true";
header("Location:". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].$sendvar);
die();
```

Comment: upvote for not only pointing out the error but ending up with better code

Comment: @DeshanR PHP redirect did not work for me for some reason. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Or a clearer way :

```
<?php
$sendvar = "?subject=".$subjectfromemail."&from=".=$from."&message=".$messagefromemail."&wrong_code=true";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
window.top.location='".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].$sendvar."';
</script>"; exit;
?>
```